# Refused to display in a frame , because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am developing a website that include a simple iframe

```
<iframe src="" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" id="product" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
```

I have this error message in the console:
Refused to display 'http://fr.allsaints.com/women/shop-accessories/allsaints-rally-keyfob/?colour=42&category=700' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

How can I do to display it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can ask whomever runs that website to grant you permission to frame it.

There's no way to bypass the explicit permission denial from a different site.

Comment: What changes/permission need to be granted in order to bypass the SAMEORIGIN issue? Please advise.

Comment: @vrh — I refer you to the second sentence of this answer.